# jquery slider not working in IE , works in chrome, firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, slider

i got a problem with a slider, its not working in internet explorer, i tested in IE 7 and 8 and i cant see it, please help
this is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() {
                var currentPosition = 0;
                var slideWidth = 200;
                var slides = $('.slider_move2');
                var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
                var slideShowInterval;
                var speed = 3000;

                slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);                 
                slides.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder2"></div>')                    
                slides.css({ 'float' : 'left' });                   
                $('#slidesHolder2').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);                  

                  function changePosition() {
                        if (currentPosition > 0) {
                            $('#slidesHolder2').css('marginLeft',0)
                                .children().first().appendTo('#slidesHolder2');
                        } else {
                            currentPosition += 1;
                        }
                        moveSlide();
                    }


                function moveSlide() {
                    $('#slidesHolder2').animate({
                        'marginLeft': slideWidth * (-currentPosition)
                    });
                }

        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: any errors in the console? What do you mean by not working?

Comment: i cannot see the images moving, some error on this line of code  'marginLeft': slideWidth * (-currentPosition), am using IE in russian,the error translates like 'Assumes the existence of '}''

Comment: Hmm, try wrapping the code like this `(slideWidth * (-currentPosition))`. Also, I think you need to add "px". Something like `(slideWidth * (-currentPosition)) + 'px'`

Comment: tried both of that, not working

Comment: Hmm, missing `;` on `slides.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder2"></div>')  `. Try changing it to `slides.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder2"></div>')  ;`

Comment: no luck yet this is where am doing it, its near the footer http://baltica.webstyle.ru/

Comment: Do i need to do anything to trigger it? I'm seeing another error in ie7, but not the one that you are describing

Answer (score 0):

This is the error I found in IE7:

```
imgWrap.animate({
    top: '0px',
    left: '135px',
    width: '700px',
    height: '400px', //<--- Remove the comma
}, sotiData.speedImg, function(){
    imgWrap.attr('onclick',  "sotBigImageHide('" + topW2 + "', '" + leftW2 + "')");
});
```

Please let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: @jobkwemoi Please be more specific. I enter the page with ie7 and i get no errors. How do i reproduce the problem?

Comment: I get no errors too on the console, the images on the slider dont show, though when i inspect element F12 the blue highlighter i can see movement(slides) but cannnot see the images